# How can I receive arbitrary props in a Svelte component and pass to a child component?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I want to receive arbitrary props from "above" and spread them onto an `<input>`, as shown here where `inputProps` would become an object containing any additional props set on this component (similar to python's `**kwargs`, in case you're familiar):

```html
<script>
export let id;
export ...inputProps;
</script>

<div>
    id: {id}
    <input {...inputProps} />
</div>
```

Can you point me toward the correct Svelte mechanism for accomplishing something like this? I have a feeling that I'm asking the wrong question, but I need a svelte developer to set me straight.  Should I use a slot instead?  Or learn about actions / "the use directive"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Svelte now also offers `$$restProps`.  See the [Svelte API Docs - Attributes and props](https://svelte.dev/docs/basic-markup#attributes-and-props).

`$$props` references all props that are passed to a component – including ones that are not declared with export. It is useful in rare cases, but not generally recommended, as it is difficult for Svelte to optimise.

```
<Widget {...$$props}/>
```

`$$restProps` contains only the props which are not declared with export. It can be used to pass down other unknown attributes to an element in a component.

```
<input {...$$restProps}>
```

Comment: $$props won't forward event handlers.

Comment: @Zheeeng does that mean in Svelte we cannot do what we do in React, wrap 3rd party components to add some custom props on top of existing ones?

Comment: Correct @Zheeeng, as of now: I believe we need to manually "forward" event handlers to child components using this nice shorthand: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/event-forwarding

Comment: @cikatomo are you asking if you can add custom props for use by the wrapper component, or to override some of the props going down to the 3rd party component?  Either should be straightforward using $$props and $$restProps. Simply export your custom props or any props that you want to override, then $$restProps will contain the props that you want to pass through to the 3rd party component.

Comment: @colllin what I mean it's not possible to send all events in one go like answer said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70551898/1079002 , github issue for that is https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2837 . So if I want to build component on top of button we have to type each event, unlike react where all props include events too

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`$$props`](https://svelte.dev/docs#Attributes_and_props) to access all the props given to a component.

> `$$props` references all props that are passed to a component –
>   including ones that are not declared with `export`. It is useful in rare
>   cases, but not generally recommended, as it is difficult for Svelte to
>   optimise.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1be2daba325143f5b34bdd9e110f5b92?version=3.16.4))**

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import Child from './Child.svelte';
</script>

<Child id="foo" placeholder="bar" />

<!-- Child.svelte -->
<script>
  let id, inputProps;
  $: ({ id, ...inputProps } = $$props);
</script>

<div>
  id: {id}
  <input {...inputProps} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While exporting you don't need to use the spread operator

```
<script>
 export let id;
 export inputProps;
</script>

<div>
 id: {id}
 <input {...inputProps} />
</div>
```

Comment: please check your link

Comment: I don't think this is what he is asking