# How to pass all event down as props to a component in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I'm creating some custom components in svelte and I didn't understood how to pass events as props such as on:click, on:mouseup, on:whatever, I tried in the followings way but they didn't work:

```
// button.svelte
// OnClick it's a prop but in this way, I need to pass every single event manually

<div on:click={OnClick} ></div>
```

or

```
// button.svelte
// I tried even in this way but it didn't really work

<div  {...$$restProps} {...$$props} ></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hierarchy is App => Outer => Inner

App:

```
<script>
    import Outer from './Outer.svelte';

    function handleMessage(event) {
        alert(event.detail.text);
    }
</script>

<Outer on:message={handleMessage}/>
```

Outer:

```
<script>
    import Inner from './Inner.svelte';
</script>

<Inner on:message />
```

Inner:

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    function sayHello() {
        dispatch('message', {
            text: 'Hello!'
        });
    }
</script>

<button on:click={sayHello}>
    Click to say hello
</button>
```

Now, this to me is event bubbling up. If you're trying to do it in a reverse way.. I'm not so sure you can achieve that. Data is passed down, events bubble up.

When it comes to trying to send all events in one big go, there seems to be this [svelte github issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2837) created to allow `on:*` syntax. Sadly it isn't yet implemented.

Comment: I already saw that example somewhere, the problem witht hat is that if I want all the event o be available I need to pass every of them one by one as a prop, I would like to pass all of them

Comment: I've edited my answer, have a look, also this comment seems to imply there might be some unofficial way of doing what [you're trying to achieve](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2837#issuecomment-522740350) and also [this comment](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2837#issuecomment-516137618) could be worth exploring

Comment: Can you not have the child component listen for events and export it's event listener function so it can be overridden via a prop? [Like this](https://svelte.dev/repl/6284d4980b5949b6bf88eb4161392729?version=3.44.3)

Comment: Seems like that could be a potential way to avoid a prop hell, can I add your suggestion to my answer?